# How to change screen for Qt app on Android

Tags: android, qt

I'm am writing an app for Android using PyQt5.
When I start my app this screen is showing first.
How can I change this?

[image: startscreen]

I already tried to change the theme to make this screen invisible, but then the user has to wait a few seconds for an app screen. 
A splash screen isn't good either, because this screen will be shown anyway 
Best solution would be to just change this one. 
But how and where?

Comment: I could be due to a function that takes a very long time called directly in the main thread: the UI will freeze and displays this kind of screen

Comment: I have seen this also in Qt C++ samples like gallery. There is no much code. Only reading the settings and setting the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself...
I have changed my ../res/values/apptheme.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The `windowDisablePreview` was just a suggestion from another person.
But I want to see a reaction when I tap an icon on my mobile.
So this is a NO GO.

But the `.NoActionBar` works for me. Now a white screen will be displayed immediatly after tapping the icon before the splash screen shows up.

To make this round here are the changes to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
    <activity  
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```